# gatsby new [site] failing: Cannot find module 'gatsby/dist/commands/develop'

Tags: babeljs, gatsby, flowtype

I'm pretty green here. I've run gatsby on this (macosx) before. It has stopped working - presumably due to an install or environment variable somewhere?

First noticed with Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "flow" relative to directory   "/Users/3Legs"

Then after installing babel presets:

npm install --global --save-dev babel-preset-flow

I get the above message:

```
gatsby develop
```

> ... Cannot find module 'gatsby/dist/commands/develop'

FULL TRAIL BELOW + babelrc

Michaels-MacBook-Air:mggatsby 3Legs$

```
gatsby new test
```

-bash: /usr/local/bin/gatsby: No such file or directory
Michaels-MacBook-Air:mggatsby 3Legs$

```
npm install --global gatsby-cli

WARN registry Unexpected warning for registry.npmjs.org: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha1-xRn2KfhrOlvtuliojTETCe7Al/k= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-xRn2KfhrOlvtuliojTETCe7Al/k= but got sha512-vE2hT1D0HLZCLLclfBSfkfTTedhVj0fubHpJBHKwwUWX0nSbhPAfk+SG9rTX95BYNmau8rGFfCeaT6T5OW1C2A==. (455516 bytes)
WARN registry Using stale package data from registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
WARN registry Unexpected warning for registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning EINTEGRITY: sha1-buxr+wdCHiFIx1xrunJCH4UwqCY= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-buxr+wdCHiFIx1xrunJCH4UwqCY= but got sha512-+ktMAh1Jwas+TnGodfCfjUbJKoANqPaJFN0z0iqh41eqD8dvguNzcitVSBSVK1pidz0AqGbLKcoVuVLRVZ/aVg==. (42903 bytes)
WARN registry Using stale package data from registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
/usr/local/bin/gatsby -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gatsby-cli/lib/index.js
+ gatsby-cli@1.1.1
added 153 packages, removed 5 packages and updated 1 package in 10.573s
Michaels-MacBook-Air:mggatsby 3Legs$ 
    gatsby new test
info Creating new site from git: git://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default.git
Cloning into 'test'...
remote: Counting objects: 566, done.
remote: Total 566 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 566
Receiving objects: 100% (566/566), 358.35 KiB | 187.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (316/316), done.
success Created starter directory layout
info Installing packages...
yarn install v0.27.5
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning "eslint-config-fbjs@1.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "babel-eslint@^6.1.2".
warning "eslint-config-fbjs@1.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^3.0.0".
warning "eslint-config-fbjs@1.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-babel@^3.3.0".
warning "eslint-config-fbjs@1.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-flowtype@^2.15.0".
warning "eslint-config-fbjs@1.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint-plugin-react@^5.2.2".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
Done in 47.94s.
Michaels-MacBook-Air:mggatsby 3Legs$ 
    cd test
Michaels-MacBook-Air:test 3Legs$ 
    gatsby develop
success delete html files from previous builds — 0.010 s
success open and validate gatsby-config.js — 0.006 s
success copy gatsby files — 0.028 s
success source and transform nodes — 0.045 s
success building schema — 0.134 s
success createLayouts — 0.039 s
success createPages — 0.016 s
success createPagesStatefully — 0.016 s
success extract queries from components — 0.118 s
success run graphql queries — 0.030 s
success write out page data — 0.006 s
success update schema — 0.094 s

info bootstrap finished - 3.856 s

error There was an error compiling the html.js component for the development server.

See our docs page on debugging HTML builds for help ...
```

> Error: Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "flow" relative to directory   "/Users/3Legs"

```
Michaels-MacBook-Air:test 3Legs$ 
    npm install --save-dev babel-preset-flow 
    npm WARN gentlyRm not removing /Users/3Legs/react/mggatsby/test/node_modules/.bin/gatsby as it wasn't installed by /Users/3Legs/react/mggatsby/test/node_modules/gatsby
    npm WARN gentlyRm not removing /Users/3Legs/react/mggatsby/test/node_modules/.bin/semver as it wasn't installed by /Users/3Legs/react/mggatsby/test/node_modules/semver
    npm WARN gentlyRm not removing /Users/3Legs/react/mggatsby/test/node_modules/jspm-registry/node_modules/.bin/semver as it wasn't installed by /Users/3Legs/react/mggatsby/test/node_modules/jspm-registry/node_modules/semver
    npm WARN gentlyRm not removing /Users/3Legs/react/mggatsby/test/node_modules/.bin/browserslist as it wasn't installed by /Users/3Legs/react/mggatsby/test/node_modules/browserslist
    npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
    npm WARN gatsby-starter-default@1.0.0 No repository field.


+ babel-preset-flow@6.23.0
removed 1375 packages and updated 6 packages in 17.729s
Michaels-MacBook-Air:test 3Legs$ 
    gatsby develop
/usr/local/bin/gatsby develop

Options:
  -h, --help     Show help                                                   [boolean]
  -H, --host     Set host. Defaults to localhost                              [string]
  -p, --port     Set port. Defaults to 8000                 [string] [default: "8000"]
  -o, --open     Open the site in your browser for you.                      [boolean]
  -v, --version  Show version number                                         [boolean]

error There was a problem loading the local develop command. Gatsby may not be installed.
```

> Error: Cannot find module 'gatsby/dist/commands/develop'

```
  - index.js:17 resolveFileName
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[resolve-from]/index.js:17:39

  - index.js:31 resolveFrom
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[resolve-from]/index.js:31:9

  - index.js:34 module.exports
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[resolve-from]/index.js:34:41

  - index.js:4 module.exports.moduleId
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[resolve-cwd]/index.js:4:30

  - create-cli.js:35 resolveLocalCommand
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/create-cli.js:35:22

  - create-cli.js:66 Object.handler
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/create-cli.js:66:7

  - command.js:233 Object.self.runCommand
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[yargs]/lib/command.js:233:22

  - yargs.js:990 Object.Yargs.self._parseArgs
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[yargs]/yargs.js:990:30

  - yargs.js:532 Object.Yargs.self.parse
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/[yargs]/yargs.js:532:23

  - create-cli.js:163 module.exports
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/create-cli.js:163:154

  - index.js:122 Object.<anonymous>
    [lib]/[gatsby-cli]/lib/index.js:122:1

Michaels-MacBook-Air:~ 3Legs$ 
    cat .babelrc 
{
  "presets": ["flow"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NPM seems to be removing modules because there isn't a package-lock.json. Not sure if this is new behavior but it's been hitting a lot of people in past few days.

All you need to do is delete node_modules and any lock file there and run `npm install`.

Comment: It is still not working for me. I tried rm -r node_modules, removing lock files, i also tried new gatsby directories/builds (gatsby new test). I still get the same errors (or if i remove node_modules and run npm install i get missing file errors (Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'config' in /Users/3Legs/react/sgcopy/node_modules/gatsby/dist/isomorphic) I even tried  npm upgrade -g  gatsby-cli  after reading this is an issue but that didn't help. Any ideas? If i can run a "gatsby new site" that will get me going.

Comment: I'd install Yarn and try using that instead.

Comment: yarn didn't work by itself ... but i ran it then tried this which did work: cat  ~/.babelrc
{
  "presets": ["flow"]
}
mv ~/.babelrc ~/.babelrcold

Comment: I'm getting this very frequently too. Can't explain why but I've been able to work around this by uninstalling any packages and then installing them again in a different order (bumped on this by chance). Tried both npm and yarn same thing.